# Vote_fu and Ajax requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been at the for hours now, trying to get vote_fu and running. I have finally made a vote on a voteable object(album), but I have to keep refreshing the page to see the effect of my Ajax knowledge with rails is basic and I have no idea where I'm going wrong with this any help would be great would be much appreciated!!!

The relevant code is as follows:

javascript file

```
application.js:

 // Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
 // This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults

 jQuery.ajaxSetup({
 'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
 })

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $("#votes_ .album").bind('click', function(e) 

 });
```

|___________________________________________________________________________________________

jquery.js
jquery-ui.js
jrails.js

Layout/appliction.html.erb (javascript added to header)

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.js', 'application.js' %>
```

---

view/votes

_album_vote.html.erb

```
<%# 
 # You can't vote if it is your quote, 
 # you are not logged in, 
 # or you have already voted on this item

 unless album.user == current_user ||
 current_user.voted_on?(@album)
%>

 <%= link_to_remote "Vote Up",
  :url => user_album_votes_path(album.user, album, :vote => :true, :format => :rjs),
  :method => :post %>




 <%= link_to_remote "Down", 
  #:url => current_user.vote_down_path(album), :vote => :false, :format => :rjs, 
  :url => user_album_votes_path(album.user, album, :vote => :false, :format => :rjs),
  :method => :post
  %> 

<%# end %>



Votes: <%= @album.votes_for - @album.votes_against %>
```

|___________________________________________________________________________________________

view/album/show:

```
<div id="votes_<%= @album.id %>" class="album_votes">
 <%= render :partial => "votes/album_vote", :locals => {:album => @album} %>
</div>
```

|___________________________________________________________________________________________

create.rjs

```
page.replace_html "votes_#{@album.id}", :partial => "album_vote", :locals => {:album => @album}
```

|___________________________________________________________________________________________

error.rjs

```
page.alert "Couldn't save your vote: You can only vote once, and you cannot vote for your own items."
```

|___________________________________________________________________________________________

I've tried playing with the ID #votes_ .album which I thought was name incorrectly but still it don't work not even an error, it's as if javascript is off !

Any help would be great!

Found the error on the server console:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Mime::RJS):
  app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:54:in `create'
  app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:52:in `create'
```

I will concur this before lights out (bed time)!

If you like give me a helping hand!

Regards

Dan

Comment: Looking over this again with the help of firebug the problem is with the application.js

1 error not sure how to fix but still looking in to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have issues with your basic jquery setup.  The following two posts have certainly helped me up the jQuery learning curve:

[jQuery Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

[Beginners Guild to jQuery and Rails](http://www.notgeeklycorrect.com/english/2009/05/18/beginners-guide-to-jquery-ruby-on-rails/)

These posts along with the amazing FireBug should get you there

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers Jonathan seen the Railscast and will follow that beginners guild.